# Add 2 tabs on top of UITableView with pages

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I would like to achieve something like that:
[image]
I have a UItableView with 2 pages and if you scroll to the right the UItable will be populated with different data, there is also a Page Control on the bottom that shows you which page the user is. I would like to have two tabs also is there a predefined way to implement it?

Comment: Do you mean UISegment instead of tabs?

Comment: thanks mate that the answer of my question

Comment: What you mean. Is that solved???